# async map state to props returning undefined while normal returns the value

Tags: reactjs, redux

```js
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import fetch from '../firebase/retrive_firebase';
import { database } from "../firebase/firebase";
import Filter_product_list from './product_list_filter';
import get_visible_products from '../selectors/get_visible_products';
class ViewProduct extends React.Component
{

    render()
    { 
        console.log(this.props.a);
        return(
            <div>
               <Filter_product_list />
            </div>   
        )
    }
}

const map_state_to_props=async(state)=>
{
    let firebase_product={}
 
     const promise=await fetch().then((response)=>{
        console.log('promise resolved');
        
        firebase_product=response
          firebase_product.map((entry)=>{console.log(entry)});
           return firebase_product
         //const filtered_products=await get_visible_products(firebase_product,state.filters);
         //console.log("filtered products",filtered_products);
    }).catch((err)=>{

    })
    console.log("what got retured from promise",promise)
     const filtered_products=get_visible_products(promise,state.filters);
    console.log("filtered products",filtered_products)
         return{
           //filtered_products,
           a:15,
        }
    // console.log("type of fetch",typeof(firebase_product))
    // firebase_product.map((product2)=>{console.log("products ",product2)});
    // console.log("product returned from fetch",firebase_product);
    // const product=get_visible_products(firebase_product,state.filters)
    // console.log("product returned from visible expenses",product);
};

export default connect(map_state_to_props,{})(ViewProduct);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**i am using async map state to props and it is returning undefined in above component with which i have connected using redux .i returned the value of map state to props as an object in which key is a and i got undefined in in console from this.props.a**

Answer (score 0):

mapStateToProps can not be async. You should perform your async action with appropriate middleware as redux-saga for instance. Basically you are performing async action in middleware, set its result to your store via reducer and propagate it to your component with mapStateToProps.